# Filling out a model from a FormCollection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I want to populate my model with data from a FormCollection.

The viewmodel I pass to my page has one property, a List of Cars.

```
public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
```

In the view I loop through each and output as a form

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Cars.Count; i++)
    {
        <form action="#" id="updateForm-@Model.Cars[i].Id" class="updateForm">
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.Hidden("Id", Model.Cars[i].Id)
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Cars[i].CarName, new { placeholder = "car name", name = "CarName", id = "CarName", @class = "user-friendly-size" })
                </div>
```

etc. Each form has its own button.

I then use JQuery to form.serialise and send the form data to the back end

```
[AjaxOnly]
    public JsonResult Update(FormCollection form)
```

As I understand it I cannot use the model binder i.e.

```
    public JsonResult Update(Car car)
```

because when the form data is serialised and posted the names come through as 
Cars[0].Id, and the model binder cannot bind. That is my understanding.

Is there are way to extract the values in the FormCollection into my model in a nice simple way? Possibly using reflection? Or am I wrong and we can bind automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use foreach loop and use properties of your car model.  Then your model should bind when posting to the Update action:

```
@foreach (var car in Model.Cars)
    {
        <form action="#" id="updateForm-@Model.Id" class="updateForm">
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.Hidden("Id", car.Id)
```

Comment: i deleted my answer because i didnt notice the OP created a new form for each car.. This is the correct answer in that case

Comment: And am I correct in saying that you cannot use TextBoxFor() here, and would have to use TextBox(car.CarName, car.CarName, new { ... })? Because TextBoxFor() requires a lambda expression.

Answer (score 0):

If you send just one Car Instance at a time you really don't need to include the iterator to render the form inputs names as each form just send the inputs inside their own scope.

Then you only need to receive one Car Model, just like you state in the original question:

```
public JsonResult Update(Car car)
```

You just need to make sure to override the default id and name given by the helper, just like you did with CarName input.